# Why is my php script not sorting an array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort data held in a variable. I first convert it to an array then try to sort it in ascending order but it seems not to be working.

Here is my code

```
$str = '"10:A", "11:Q", "12:V", "13:A", "14:G", "15:I", "16:E", "17:D", "18:N", "19:R", "1:A", "20:U", "2:X", "3:C", "4:D", "5:R", "6:U", "7:V", "8:I", "9:S"';
$cars = (explode(",",$str));
$cars = array($cars);

sort($cars, 1);
$clength=count($cars);
for($x=0;$x<$clength;$x++)
  {
  echo $cars[$x];
  echo "<br>";
  }
```

Any workaround this?

Comment: where is the code to sort? can only see it prints the split result..

Comment: $str = '"10:A", "11:Q", "12:V", "13:A", "14:G", "15:I", "16:E", "17:D", "18:N", "19:R", "1:A", "20:U", "2:X", "3:C", "4:D", "5:R", "6:U", "7:V", "8:I", "9:S"';
$cars = (explode(",",$str));

asort($cars, 1);
$clength=count($cars);
for($x=0;$x<$clength;$x++)
  {
  echo $cars[$x];
  echo "<br>";
  }

Answer (score 0):

try rsort

```
$str = '"10:A", "11:Q", "12:V"';
    $cars = (explode(",",$str));

    rsort($cars);
    $clength=count($cars);
    for($x=0;$x<$clength;$x++)
      {
      echo $cars[$x];
      echo "<br>";
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort according to number try this:

```
<?php
function my_sort($a,$b)
{
  $intval_a = filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  $intval_b = filter_var($b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  if(intval($intval_a) > intval($intval_b))
    return 1;
}
$str = '"10:A", "11:Q", "12:V", "13:A", "14:G", "15:I", "16:E", "17:D", "18:N", "19:R", "1:A", "20:U", "2:X", "3:C", "4:D", "5:R", "6:U", "7:V", "8:I", "9:S"';
$cars = explode(',',$str);
$cars = ($cars);

usort($cars, "my_sort");
$clength=count($cars);
for($x=0;$x<$clength;$x++)
{
  echo $cars[$x];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I've noticed. First, you've exploded the string which produces an array. You're then putting that array into another array and trying to sort that. You should remove the line `$cars = array($cars);`

I'd also recommend removing the quotes and spaces from the string before trying to sort them, so you are doing the sort on `10:A` instead of `"10:A"`, for example.

The other thing is the sort function should take a flag as the second parameter which defines the type of sort to perform. See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) for the different flags you have available. I'm guessing you want it to be sorted

> 1:A, 2:X, 3:C...

instead of

> 1:A, 10:A, 11:Q...

in which case you should use the `SORT_NATURAL` flag. (Alternatively, you could use the `natsort` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)).

These changes would give the following code:

```
$str = '"10:A", "11:Q", "12:V", "13:A", "14:G", "15:I", "16:E", "17:D", "18:N", "19:R", "1:A", "20:U", "2:X", "3:C", "4:D", "5:R", "6:U", "7:V", "8:I", "9:S"';
$str = str_replace(array('"', ' '), '', $str);
$cars = explode(",",$str);

sort($cars, SORT_NATURAL);
$clength = count($cars);
for($x = 0; $x < $clength; $x++) {
    echo $cars[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use natsort() function

```
$str = '"10:A", "11:Q", "12:V", "13:A", "14:G", "15:I", "16:E", "17:D", "18:N", "19:R", "1:A", "20:U", "2:X", "3:C", "4:D", "5:R", "6:U", "7:V", "8:I", "9:S"';
$cars = (explode(",",$str));

natsort($cars);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($cars);
foreach($cars as $car)
{
    echo $car."<br>";
}
```

[Check here](https://3v4l.org/qVH9J)

Hope this will help.